# How do I move a site from the top bar to the side bar

Tags: navigation

I am trying to move a site from the top bar to appear in the side bar - how do I do that?

Comment: can you add some screen shots of what it looks like now and what you want?

Comment: Please add some details of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using SharePoint 2010. Go to Site Actions - Site Settings. Under Look and feel you should see a Navigation link.

Under the Navigation Editing and Sorting section you can delete or hide the Site under Global Navigation (top) and add it to Current Navigation (side bar).

Comment: Thanks so much, when I go there this is the menu I see:     Look and Feel 
Title, description, and icon 
Quick launch 
Top link bar 
Tree view 
Site theme    Which one of these would do what you have just suggested?  Thanks!

Comment: @Pam you will have to go into two of those subsections to do what Richard is saying - go into "Top link bar" to remove the link from the top bar, and go into "Quick launch" to add a new link on the side bar.

Comment: OR - you can just paste http:// yoursiteURL/_layouts/AreaNavigationSetings.aspx into your browser to get directly to the page Richard was talking about.  The "Navigation" link to that page only shows up if you have the Publishing feature enabled.  (But you can still get to it without the feature by using the URL directly.)

Comment: Thanks all for your help!  I have been able to move the site to the side bar navigation.  :)